# Is there an English expression which corresponds to the French "péage"?

Tags: single-word-requests

**The practice of paying through the nose for every little thing**

You have to hand it to the French: they're elegant, this highway sign, when I first saw it, made me laugh:

[image: French road sign on the A8 near Aix]

Notice the word "péage" under Nimes and another one under Avignon. Isn't it so much more poetic than the matter-of-fact American "toll ahead"? It rhymes with "garage" pronounced the American way, with the stress on the second syllable.

It got me thinking, though. The "-age" suffix, introduced to the English language by William's cronies, no doubt, a nifty little thing, has given us such words as "trackage," "postage," "usage," "windage" (the portion of a vessel's surface upon which the wind acts), and so forth - and lends itself to word ... uh ... coinage.

It means, according to Dictionary.com, "process, the outcome of," etc.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-age

I wonder if there is a word ending in that suffix that means

> **paying through the nose for every little thing**

(I tried Anglicizing the French word "péage" to "payage", by moving the stress to the first syllable, but it sounds awkward).

Any suggestions welcome; as are neologisms.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31988/discussion-on-question-by-ricky-what-is-an-english-word-ending-age-which-corr).

Comment: Removing the irrelevant “(flagged) offensive comments about the French” in edit 8 was, imo, very well explained & justified. Not so (again, in my opinion), however, RE the removal of the OP’s request for neologisms. If the “neologisms” tag exists for others/all to use, wouldn’t its addition to this question have been a more suitable/fair way to go; keeping in mind 1) the OP’s intent & 2) that the addition of “an English word ending [in?] *-age*” to the title (which might imply that neologisms aren't welcome, despite the OP adding in edit 7 that they were) was not the OP’s doing? @AndrewLeach

Comment: @PapaPoule The neologisms tag is to ask **about** neologisms, not **for** them. Asking for them is off-topic, as it simply creates a list. You can see the "What questions should I ask/not ask" in the Help (I can't link easily on a tablet). SE deals in substantive, verifiable and impartial fact — as far as that applies to a language, in our case.

Comment: It's a toll, but the word has nothing to do with the word "pay" (also prononc. of pé- is unrelated to that of _payer/paie_ in Fr.).; it's related to the latin word for _foot_. In fact the OOD has [_pedage_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pedage) (hist./rare, obs.) which reflects this. Which shows up in a version of the Wyclef bible (like: _if that cite were bild vp and the wallis of it enstorid tribute and pedage and 3eris rentus thei shul not 3iue_) says [NED](https://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/604/mode/1up). The right to pass on foot, basically _passage_. Thanks.

Comment: @Làchus'n'AI: My apologies. I'm actually fluent in French. My question post did make perfect sense until Andrew Leach, in his infinite wisdom, decided dramatically to improve it.

Comment: The original question asks if there is an English word ending in *age* meaning: *paying through the nose for every little thing*. I've broaden the request to include expression in the title.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder if there is a word ending in that suffix that means "paying"?

**Damage**—as in, "What's the damage?"—a question regarding the price or fee to be incurred. ([Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=What%27s+the+damage%3F) | [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What's+the+damage%3F))

Comment: +1 (although not quite as cute as "stingage"!)

Comment: The comment about this and stingage seemed to have disappeared, so I thunk, bar grit, I'll post it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you cite regarding showers and after-hours service, you don't seem to object to being charged for the room. In that context, that is, if you accept the primary cost and want a term for only the incremental costs, try [*surcharge*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/surcharge).

> 1. an additional charge, tax, or cost - dictionary.com

This, of course, doesn't address the issue of having very many of them. For that, since you invite neologisms, may I suggest *a paper cut of surcharges* ?

Comment: Common sense would suggest that people do have to actually _pay_ for things, or there would be no motivation for those who produce those things to do so. I mostly object to the philosophy some people seem to cultivate that anything and everything can yield a measure of profit. Or, when something is actually free, the government will step in and take all the joy out of it by regulating it, putting a fence around it, and sending in a motorized police corps to hand out court summonses to beer drinkers and cigarette smokers (the beach at Coney Island this year).

Comment: @Ricky Good, the first two points in your comment are what I thought you meant. The third I hadn't considered in my answer. You might call that situation *micromanagement*, or sometimes *nanny state* - no money paid; it's 'just' bureaucracy. (Though I'm in favour of smoking bans for the health and comfort of non-smokers. With alcohol, the objection is mainly against glass litter and antisocial behaviour.)

Comment: @Ricky Can you re-edit the title of the Q to make it more attractive?

Comment: @ab2: No point. As I mentioned to Matt earlier, Andrew Leach zapped the comments that contained definitions for the proposed words and edited my question in such a way that it's barely intelligible now, thinking this would greatly improve things. There's absolutely no guarantee that he won't do it again, or put it on hold, or close it, so why bother.

Comment: @Ricky Why not?  Play the game!  My attempt: "What is an English word ending in -age that describes the proliferation of user fees?"  Or omit ("ending in -age).  Or, "word or short expression"....

Comment: @ab2: Stoop to their level? My original question was precise, elegantly worded, and contained a helpful story to facilitate answering. I invested time and energy - I always do, as a matter of courtesy to others. Doing it all over again after getting plenty of good answers (look at the list, and look at your own answer) would be ... hmm ... humiliating. Until frivolous editing is penalized (5000 rep points or so), this place is going to continue to be terrorized by frustrated schoolmarms who never ask questions because they already know everything.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit in which the OP asked the question, I offer ***abusage***, pronounced in Fake French to rhyme with garage.

User fees are well known to anyone who travels via the airlines.  There is a user fee for checking baggage, for food (if so it can be called), for changing one's flight, for getting a seat that can accommodate a full-grow adult (Economy Plus)...I've probably forgotten a few.  User fees have been proposed, whether seriously or semi-seriously, I am not sure. for the overhead bins and for the toilets (but not for the barf bags, for an obvious reason).

User (the customer) gives rise to abuser (the imposer of excessive user fees on the customer) to **abusage**, the custom of applying a user fee for everything -- the OP's question.

I can't give a reference for **abusage**, pronounced to rhyme with garage, but if enough of us use it, it will be in a dictionary in a few years.

**Abusage** (rhymes with usage) however, is a pedigreed word.  "Abusage first appeared in the 16th century as a general synonym of abuse, but it fell into disuse after just a couple of centuries. The word reemerged in the language with a new grammar-specific sense after Eric Partridge published a book on grammar titled *Usage and Abusage* in 1942."  Wikitionary (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abusage)

Answer (score 0):

The French word *péage* doesn't come from the verb *payer* (if it did, it would probably be *paiage* or something). Instead, it is rooted in the word for *foot*.

Therefore, we have a quite logical word **footage** which parallels nicely with words like *yardage* and *mileage*, the latter of which is frequently used in the sense of paying ("my company pays my mileage").

But practically speaking, you'd be better off just using *mileage* because it's in use in the payment sense-ish. *Yardage* isn't ever used but for distance and my ear would ear *footage* in a similar way.